# C sharp com linux

Tags: c#, linux

Já tenho instalado o meu atom no meu linux
Gostaria de saber como faço para compilar os meus codigos em C sharp ?

Comment: De uma olhada nessa [resposta](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55461406/5322399), pode lhe ajudar

Comment: Já tem o mono instalado ?

Comment: Instala o .NET Core e o .NET Core SDK.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Eu uso o visual studio code, pois possui muitos plugins para C# e é compatível com o Linux, já o Atom possui o omnisharp-atom package.

Comment: Certo possui o `omnisharp-atom` package, mas como faz para compilar um ficheiro em C# com esse package ? Sem detalhar isso a sua resposta não responde à pergunta feita, pelo menos não de forma completa.